# Eclipse JPA project - defining connection to Oracle RAC

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jpa, jdbc

Recently I wanted to play a bit with Eclipse and JPA. Thus I wanted to create a JPA project.

I got stuck when specifying the database connection, as **editing** the "Connection URL" (shown on the image) **is not possible** and I want to enter a (**good, working**) connection string to an Oracle RAC server which looks more or less like that:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=...
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Or is it a "feature" of the **Data Source Explorer**?

[Screenshot from Eclipse http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4876/stacku.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4876/stacku.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Oracle's FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.html#05_04) for syntax of the database connection string.

Comment: It is not the problem of the JDBC syntax (well to some point it is, as Eclipse forces me to stick with the @:: format).

As I have said I have a good connection string in a given format and would like to use it with Eclipse DataSource.

Comment: If Eclipse doesn't allow you to edit the Connection URL field, why not specify the SID/Host/Port number/User name/Password fields separately? If I understand correctly, you should be able to extract those parameters from your good connection string.

Comment: No, I cannot, this will not work for RAC (at least in my setup).

Comment: Found a blog comment that suggests the following syntax: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host1^host2:1521:service_name` (see http://www.jugpadova.it/articles/2007/04/11/jdbc-url-for-oracle-rac).
Other than that, I'm out of ideas... Good luck!

Comment: Answered proved to be pretty trivial. I have added the Oracle Thin driver as the 'Other Driver'. After that I was ably to put any connection string I wanted for the connection using this driver.